# mongodb - unable to insert record

Tags: c#, mongodb, visual-studio-2015, robo3t

I have this code:

```
public async void SaveAuditLog(AuditLog a)
{
    var db = new MongoDBContext();
    var o = db.GetMongoDatabase(Common.Common.MongoDbConnectionString);

    var audit = o.GetCollection<AuditLog>("AuditLog");

    await audit.InsertOneAsync(a);
}

public IMongoDatabase GetMongoDatabase(string connectionstring)
{
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionstring);
    return client.GetDatabase("test");
}
```

this is the connection string from web.config:

```
<add connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017" name="mongodb"></add>
```

when I check the data through robomongo, it does not show me any data inserted.

I have tried the following code as well and no data is inserted:

```
public async void SaveAuditLog(AuditLog a)
{
    var client = new MongoClient(Common.Common.MongoDbConnectionString);
    var o = client.GetDatabase("test");

    var audit = o.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("AuditLog");

    var document = new BsonDocument { {"Test", "test"} };

    await audit.InsertOneAsync(document);
}
```

I am using `csharpdriver` for mongo with 2.2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I see you don't specify the database name, that might be the problem, heppened to me. Check it out. Let us know.

Comment: it is specified in the second method client.GetDatabase("test")

Comment: I must have missed it, sorry.

Comment: i added this code to test as well and it's printing the _ids:   Console.WriteLine(a._id);
            Console.ReadKey(); but when i check the data, there is no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found out that the data is getting inserted in mongodb and there is a bug in robomongo version 0.8.5 itself which does not show collections/documents for mongodb version 3 and above.

ran some scripts (in robomongo) which do return the data:

```
 db.stats()

db.CollectionName.find()
```

downloaded mongochef and it displayed the data straight away.